# Is there a keyboard shortcut to move the position of the Dock?

Tags: keyboard, dock

Can I move the Dock using a keyboard shortcut?

If there is no default keyboard shortcut, is it possible to set this up using a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no default, but you could probably use AppleScript to accomplish this.  Hmm...

## EDIT:

Make an AppleScript to run this shell script:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock orientation -string left;killall Dock
```

Comment: I'm in the 'extreme idiot' category with regard to AppleScript. What would such a script look like?

Comment: Yep: create an AppleScript to run shell script:
    defaults write com.apple.Dock orientation -string left;killall Dock
...then use the Keyboard system preferences, or your favorite launcher app such as the awesome Quicksilver, to assign a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: macscripter.net is a good starting point for learning AS.  opening the Terminal and trying: defaults read com.apple.Dock will help you start to learn what the preferences are and how to manipulate them.