# Is there any way to change the mac dock's position with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator, dock

I don't think there are default shortcuts for that. But I assume you could make one using AppleScript or other automation programs.

I found [this post from 2012](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46046/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-the-position-of-the-dock) asking the same question. I tried making the script provided in the comments but couldn't make it work.

I'm not sure if it isn't working because Apple Scripts are different now, or because the script per se doesn't work or because there are steps I'm skipping.

When I try to save the script it says

> “Expected “given”, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found identifier.”

Any idea?

Answer (score 12):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell dock preferences
    if screen edge is bottom then
        set screen edge to left
    else if screen edge is left then
        set screen edge to bottom
    end if
end tell
```

In Automator, create a new Service or Quick Action and add a run AppleScript action to that workflow, adding the above AppleScript code.  Then in System Preferences you can create a keyboard shortcut for that new service.

Comment: Nice! +1 I seem to always forget about `dock preferences` in System Events. :)

Comment: Awesome! I was just looking for a way to make this exact same toggle (left vs bottom) without using `killall Dock`. Thanks!

Comment: This works, unlike the `defaults write` approach. Which is annoying because that is a lot shorter.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the **Syntax Error**:

> Expected “given”, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found identifier.

From:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock orientation -string left;killall Dock
```

In **Script Editor** is because it is not **AppleScript** *code*!

It's a compound command to run in **Terminal**; however, it can be run in **AppleScript** by using the `do shell script` *command*:

```applescript
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.Dock orientation -string left;killall Dock"
```

That said though, I'd choose not to use it because the result of `killall Dock` with unhide all hidden windows and can be very disruptive and messy.

An alternative is to use **UI Scripting**<sup>1</sup> with **System Preferences**, and this can be done in a less disruptive manner then `killall Dock`. <sup>1</sup>Note that using **UI Scripting** may require [accessibility privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) be granted.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will toggle the position of the **Dock** between the **Bottom** and the **Left** side of the screen:

<sup>This was tested in Script Editor and works under macOS High Sierra.</sup>

```applescript
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
end if

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.01
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal anchor "Main" of pane id "com.apple.preference.dock"

tell application "System Events" to tell application process "System Preferences"
    repeat while not (exists (window "Dock"))
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    tell radio group 1 of window "Dock"
        if value of radio button "Bottom" is 1 then
            click radio button "Left"
        else if value of radio button "Left" is 1 then
            click radio button "Bottom"
        end if
    end tell
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"
```

---

This *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be used in an **Automator** *Service* (*Quick Action* in **macOS Mojave**) using a **Run AppleScript** *action*, and assigned a keyboard shortcut in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.

Comment: Hmmm.. Some of those lines look familiar LOL. Gonna have to +1 ;-)

Comment: Yes, we both have gleaned code from each other! :) Thanks for the +1